# Microbit python Invalid syntax

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

I'm trying out the BBC microbit educational computer for my kids. I thought I'd do something simple, like traverse an array, using buttons A & B to increment left and right (looping at the ends). I can't work out what's wrong with my code (reports syntax error on line 3)? Also is my presumption about 'input →' and 'basic →' relating to the microbit import at the top correct?

`# Add your Python code here. E.g.
from microbit import *
function main ()
    var alphabet := ""
    var alphabetIndex := 0
    input → on button pressed(A) do
        if alphabetIndex = 1 then
            alphabetIndex := 27
        else add code here end if
        alphabetIndex := alphabetIndex - 1
    end
    input → on button pressed(B) do
        if alphabetIndex = 26 then
            alphabetIndex := 0
        else add code here end if
        alphabetIndex := alphabetIndex + 1
    end
    basic → forever do
        basic → show number(alphabetIndex, 150)
    end
    for 0 ≤ i < 1 do
        alphabetIndex := 1
        alphabet := "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    end for
    basic → show string(alphabet[alphabetIndex], 150)
end function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid Python code. Python functions usually start with `def main():`

The first two lines with

```
# Add your Python code here. E.g.
from microbit import *`
```

are valid python though.

The code following that is intended for the 'TouchDevelop' environment for the BBC Micro. Make a new code file and be sure select the TouchDevelop editor if you would like to try and run that code.

Answer (score 0):

After Dennis pointed out that I wasn't using Python, I took another go. This time it worked. :)

```
    from microbit import *

    alphabetIndex = 0
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    while True:
        if  button_a.is_pressed():
            if (alphabetIndex == 0):
                alphabetIndex = 26
            alphabetIndex = alphabetIndex - 1

        if  button_b.is_pressed():
            if (alphabetIndex == 25):
                alphabetIndex = -1
            alphabetIndex = alphabetIndex + 1

        display.scroll(alphabet[alphabetIndex])
```

Comment: Hi Gregg, just as a heads up for next time, it's good ethos to mark @Dennis Shtatnov as the correct answer as he did provide you it after all ;)

Comment: Sorry,  I hadn't been back in ages. Amended accordingly :)